# Dataframe unique items and x y locations to a grid of roomates (shared location) items

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, location, vectorization

I have dataframe looks like this example,
Where id is unique but ids can share location, like id 1 and 2 sharing 0,0 cell

```
 | id  |  x  |  y  |  
-----------------------
1|  1  |  0  |  0  | 
2|  2  |  0  |  0  | 
3|  3  |  1  |  2  |
4|  4  |  1  |  0  |
.
.
```

I want to get a dataframe of roommates such as:
Where index and columns are the according to the id and values are 1 if share cell and 0 otherwise

```
 |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  | ... 
---------------------------
1|  0  |  1  |  0  |  0  |
2|  1  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
3|  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
4|  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
.
.
```

Because this is big dataframe, the function need be vectorized and not using `apply` methods which are basically looping over rows

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = df1.to_numpy()
arr = arr[1:]
```

```
mask = (arr[:, np.newaxis] == arr).prod(axis= 2)
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(mask)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would help to improve the quality of your answer. Remember that you are also answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.